# How to get file path from input using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I'm working on chrome browser, I want to get path file from input tag, I use the code as below:

```
$('input[type=file]').val() //C:\fakepath\test.csv
```

But result isn't as my expect.
please help me resolve it. Thanks

Comment: add double quotes in file      $('input[type="file"]').val();

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper That's not required.. and that does not relate anything with the problem..

Comment: yes,i know,this is used only to get value...not path @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy